# .NET MAUI - How come binding isn't working with ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I have a class "CellularInfo" where I am trying to display items in an Observable Collection, but the binding of `Rssi`, `Rsrp`, and `Rsrq` are not showing.

I know that LTEInfo is getting populated in CellularInfo.xaml.cs, but it's not binding.

Cellularinfo.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CellularSignal1"
             x:Class="CellularSignal1.CellularInfo"
             Title="Signal">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <ListView BackgroundColor="Red" ItemsSource="{x:Reference lteStrengths}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Rssi}" HeightRequest="50"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Rsrp}" HeightRequest="50"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Rsrq}" HeightRequest="50"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

CellularInfo.xaml.cs:

```
namespace CellularSignal1;

using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Telephony;
using Java.Util.Logging;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

public partial class CellularInfo : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<LTEInfo> lteStrengths { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<LTEInfo>();

    public CellularInfo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
       addSignalStrengths();
    }

    public void addSignalStrengths()
    {
       LTEInfo lte = new LTEInfo
      {
          Rssi = 3,
          Rsrp = 2,
          Rsrq = 7,
          Level = 8
      };
      lteStrengths.Add(lte);
    }
  }
```

LTEInfo.cs:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace CellularSignal1
{
    public class LTEInfo : ObservableObject
    {

        public int Rssi { get; set; }
        public int Rsrp { get; set; }
        public int Rsrq { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: AddsignalStrengths() creates an object but are not adding it to the collection

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the fact that I am adding to the collection. I was trying to remove some code that is not relevant, and accidentally had deleted that.

Comment: Your `class LTEInfo : ObservableObject` is not using `ObservableObject` correctly: you cannot use `{ get; set; }` properties: [you need to use long-form properties that invoke `SetProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject).

Comment: Also, `public ObservableCollection<LTEInfo> lteStrengths { get; set; }` should be named `LteStrengths` and have just `{ get; }` without a `set;`. In C#/.NET, all properties in all types should have `PascalCased` names, not `camelCase` names (`camelCase` is for fields, locals, and parameters, not properties and methods).

Comment: Hi, Dai. I have tried with SetProperty, but still have the same issue. So as not to change underlying code on here, I pasted what I created on LTEInfo.cs here: https://pastecode.io/s/vz8ww5r9. I also appreciate the insight on the naming convention, but haven't implemented since I'm focused on the underlying issue right now.

Comment: I think you should switch to using a dedicated ViewModel (Search for "MVVM Pattern") instead of putting your data-members inside the View's class. Also, have you verified that your `OnAppearing` method is ever actually called?

Comment: I think I will in the future when I need a view model, but I don't think I should need one right now as my code is still small. This is just from the research I have done. I understand MVVM is nice, and I understand the need for it, but I don't think all code should required that pattern. Yes, I have verified that I am getting one LTEInfo added to lteStrengths.

Comment: You need to assign `BindingContext = this;` in the page constructor

Comment: If I put that in the code, my x:reference throws an error then...

It would be nice if someone could provide a whole and complete answer instead of trying all of these guesses, and failing every time. I guess that just might be the nature of the beast right now with .Net Maui...

I have updated the code to everybody's answers that doesn't throw an error thus far.

Comment: "throws an error" is not a very helpful description of the problem.  It is difficult and time consuming to provide a "complete" answer because we don't know everything that is wrong with your code.  Only you can actually build and run it to test it.

Comment: I understand it's difficult. What I meant is that it then said the x:reference didn't exist. Issues like that can be seen by me, but when something is not being bound or output correctly, I have no idea where to go, since there's no errors, it just doesn't output...

Anyways, thank you for your answer. That worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change your `ItemsSource` to

```
<ListView BackgroundColor="Red" ItemsSource="{Binding lteStrengths}">
```

and set your `BindingContext` in the constuctor

```
public CellularInfo()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = this;
}
```